# How to check if a value does not exist in elasticsearch attribute?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a json object with system environments. I need to list out that percolator if `environment variable does not contain a variable name "JAVA_HOME"` **and** also if `JAVA_HOME's value is not present in PATH variable`. Is this possible in Elasticsearch?

below is my percolator

```
PUT /eg/.percolator/2
{   
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
               "bool": {
                   "must": [
                      {
                          "match": {
                             "client.name": "Athena"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "match": {
                             "client.environment.variable.@name": "JAVA_HOME"
                          }
                      }
                    ]                   
               }               
           }
        }
    }  
}
```

my doc

```
GET /eg/message/_percolate
{
    "doc": {
        "client": {
            "name": "Athena",
            "environment": {
                "variable": [
                    {
                        "@name": "JAVA_HOME",
                        "@value": "/home/vikrant/Linux/Sandra/java"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "PATH",
                        "@value": "/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/vikrant/Linux/FAS611:/home/vikrant/Linux/FAS611/odbc:/home/vikrant/Linux/Sandra/java/bin:/home/vikrant/Linux/Sandra/server/bin:.:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/etc:/etc:/usr/etc:.:/databases/ORACLE/bin:/databases/SYBASE/OCS-15_0/bin:/databases/DB2/bin:/usr/odbc/bin"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your current query working at all? Your docs are nested.

Answer (score 0):

You need [nested mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) first since your docs have nesting. This is the mapping that I first created for your docs to make things work:

```
{
  "nested_exp": {
    "properties": {
      "client": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "environment": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "variable": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "@name": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "@value": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I changed your provided query to make it work as you expected:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "client",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "client.name": "Athena"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "client.environment.variable",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "client.environment.variable.@name": "JAVA_HOME"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Coming to your question, it has two parts.

For the first part, you can use the `NOT` filter with `nested` match filter. Something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "client",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "client.name": "Athena"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "filtered": {
                "query": {
                  "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": {
                  "not": {
                    "filter": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "client.environment.variable",
                        "query": {
                          "match": {
                            "client.environment.variable.@name": "JAVA_HOME"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I just tried on my local Elasticsearch server and it works like a charm.

The second one seems difficult to implement with Elasticsearch only as what you what to query is something like `value of 1 variable should not be present in another variable's value`.

Comment: Can you please help me with [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690293/how-to-match-an-array-value-by-its-key-in-a-key-value-pair-elasticsearch-array)? Thanks